# AO baking for modular environments that will be moved/rotated?

Tags: baking

I need help in baking in such a way that my modular environment will line up regardless of direction or position. Can it be made internally or do I need xNormal or similar?

(Images are with diffuse on top)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could change the AO distance to avoid that the shadows reach the border of the assets.
Go in Blender Render mode, in the World tab, search the Gather line and reduce the Attenuation Distance Value:

[image]

Even if the option are grey they will change the AO, also they work for Cycles.